# Fastening sheet steel on nylon

Tags: mechanism

I'm trying to attach a small piece of sheet steel (30mm x 50mm x 1mm) to a small piece of nylon (50mm x 50mm x 4mm). Does anyone know how they could be fastened using small screws (

Any thought appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just use machine screws. Drill clearance holes in the steel, drill narrower holes through the nylon. Then it will be easy to hand tap threads in the nylon with an appropriate tap for the screws you are using. Threads in nylon will be fine for light-duty use.

(Where I am metric screws are common, and I'd use M3 or maybe M4 screws with the standard pitch, these should be available in a short length.)

Comment: I agree with @Andy: for most applications you can just drill and tap nylon.   For applications with higher loads, you can use the knurled threaded inserts which are made for thermoplastics.  See, for example, this web page: http://www.ezlok.com/inserts-for-plastic/press-inserts.

Answer (score 1):

Consider attaching a [pemnut](https://www.google.com/search?site=imghp&tbm=isch&q=pemnut) or a [nutsert](https://www.google.com/search?site=imghp&tbm=isch&q=nutsert) to the steel sheet, then using a screw from the nylon side into those threads.

You might also consider drilling and threading several holes in the steel, screwing in short studs or screws, brazing them into place (or using threadlocker or epoxy), then grinding or polishing the steel surface.
[Self-clinching threaded studs](http://www.thefabricator.com/product/assembly/self-clinching-threaded-studs-designed-for-thin-metal-assemblies) are another possibility.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of screws, how about simlpe magnetic force? I extracted this parts from old harddisk drives, the real forceful parts are the small ones on the top. You wouldn't believe that this magnetic force could exist close to a disk drive.

[image]